# How can I leverage the camera to detect certain occurrences?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, camera

This is kind of what a barcode scanner does, except I do not wish to detect a barcode (I will write the code for what I want to detect). How do I even set up the camera so it is a continuos scanner? Like the user just presses a play button and the camera will automatically scan for stuff? Just as an example, say I wish to run the scanner until the camera runs into the event that the whole screen is pure black, at which point it will display the message "detected all black".

Answer (score 0):

There is an older Apple Technical Q&A that details how to use AVFoundation to continuously generate low resolution UIImages from a video capture session that you could then sample and use for your detection:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html